# Having packery grid items have opacity layer over them for hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to mimic this animation over my grid items in my packery grid when the user hovers over them (note the grid items contain background images):

http://thefoxwp.com/portfolio-packery-4-columns/

To do this they use the technique highlighted here:
https://jsfiddle.net/q0d2rqt0/5/

where a overlay div is hidden underneath another div to act like another layer on top of it:

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  //background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/380/222/nature");
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-out;
}

.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to accomplish this with my packery grid, but I am unsure how I can accomplish this because I do not know how to make my overlay div layer move along with my packery grid when it acts responsively.

I can identify the hover effect over each item in the grid fine with:

```
  $container.on('mouseenter', ".item", function (event) {
      var target = event.target;
      var $target = $(target); 

      //code here to make the opacity adjustment to white on hover on
});

$container.on('mouseleave', ".item-", function (event) {
      var target = event.target;
      var $target = $(target);

      //code here to make the opacity adjustment reverse when hover away
});
```

So I have identified the hovering mechanism here with the correct grid item no matter where its location is, but I am having trouble with the CSS to make the opacity go to white on hover without an overlay div layer.

Item Css:

```css
.item1 {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
   -webkit-filter: saturate(1); 
    filter: saturate(1); 
}

.item-content1 {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
      border:1px solid #021a40;

  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
     -moz-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
       -o-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
          transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    
}

.item1.is-expanded {
  width: 375px;
  height: 400px;
}

.item1:hover { 
    cursor: pointer; 

}

.item1:hover .item-content1 {
}

.item1.is-expanded {
  z-index: 2;
}

.item1.is-expanded .item-content1 {
  
}

.item1.is-viewed {
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-filter: sepia(1) hue-rotate(200deg);
    filter: sepia(1) hue-rotate(200deg);
}
```

Any idea? Can I simply add something to image: hover with a webkit transition? Am I misunderstanding the concept of an opacity layer here since I am using a background image for my grid? The problem seems to be that background image is not animatable.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly,
Best practice is to use a container with 'overflow:hidden', and hide the masked content with 'transform: translate' with height equal to the container. 100% width will work responsively with any content.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/Nirsgv/pen/NxbYex)

css:

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.org-content {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
}

.mask {
  height: 300px;
  top: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3aa6db;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in 0s;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container:hover>.mask {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease-out 0.2s;
  transform: translate(0px, -300px);
  transition: all ease-in 0.25s;
}
```

html:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="mask">
    masked content
  </div>
  <div class='org-content'>
    original content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question really pertains to packery and the issue that it seems I cannot add a div mask like you have because I do not have the guarantee it is going to be in the same spot as it. Packery is a framework that offers these masonry responsive grids with moving items and I am not sure how to keep track where to put the overlay mask div component.